# Ruby: Using a regular expression to find and open a file based on its filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to test the contents of a file that is generated from code. The problem is that the full name of the file is based on a timestamp `abc123_#{d.strftime('%Y%m%d%I%M%S')}.log`

How could I use `File` to find this file and read it? I tried doing `File.exists?()` with a regular expression as the parameter but that didn't work.

I found this in another question on stackoverflow:

`File.basename(file_path).match(/_.*(css|scss|sass)/)`

How would I be able to use that in my case where the file is located in my`public` folder?

**ANSWER**

So the two answers below both work and I used a combination of them.

`Dir['public/*.log'].select { |f| f =~ /purge_cc_website/}`

The `*` acts as a wildcard that is sort of a regular expression in itself. After that you filter the array using an actual regex.

Comment: Might be slightly faster to do `f.include?('purge_cc_website')` since it doesn't include a regex.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Dir[]` takes a file glob so, if your pattern isn't too complicated, you can just do:

```
Dir['public/abc123_*.log']
```

More glob info [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

Answer (score 19):

`File` is for reading one file. You need to use `Dir` to find files by name.

```
files = Dir['*'].select {|x| x =~ /_.*(css|scss|sass)/ }
```

If you just want the last file in the case of dups:

```
files = Dir['*'].select {|x| x =~ /_.*(css|scss|sass)/ }.sort.last
```